# Fixing method conflict between classes?

Tags: java, arraylist

In my Character class I have the simple method `getHealth`:

```
public int getHealth(){
    return health;
}
```

In another class, I have the following method

```
public static void playerCombat(ArrayList attacking, ArrayList targets){
```

This method takes an 2 arrays of 3 character.

I also have condition that it can only run while the players health is > 0.

```
    public static void playerCombat(ArrayList attacking, ArrayList targets){
         While(attacking.get(0).getHealth() > 0){
               blablabla
         }
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Driver.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getHealth()
location: class java.lang.Object
```

but in the Main method right below I use the getHealth() method and it work fine. How do I fix this/why does it work in the main method but not this one?

Comment: It's `while`, not `While`. `attacking` contains *objects* of what type?

Comment: `getName` or `getHealth`? Please post the *real* code you are using.

Comment: looks like you are trying to call the method getHealth on an object of type `Object`.

Comment: It's getHealth, fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using raw collections types instead of parameterized types, so Java doesn't know that what's in your collections are `Character`s. You should be getting a warning about this; it's there for a reason. (By the way, `Character` is a bit of a dangerous class name, since it conflicts with `java.lang.Character`.)

Replace your `ArrayList` parameters with `ArrayList<Character>`, or better yet, just `List<Character>`.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about the class name but I did what I was told and got zero errors pertaining to that. And thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: @Howcan You can have lots of classes named the same thing in different packages, but it's easy to accidentally refer to the wrong one, especially if it's the same as one in `java.lang` or a common utility package (`util`, for example), or if someone uses a `*` import (which is bad but common practice). It's best to avoid the standard names if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with using a * import? Just wondering because that's what I've been doing. This question is going overy offtopic but I don't really mind I learned a few things and got what I needed.

Comment: @Howcan Search for the question. Basically, what you're importing can change without notice, breaking future compiles.

Answer (score 0):

`get(0)` returning `Object`. You need to cast

```
YourCharacterClass c = (YourCharacterClass)attacking.get(0);
 While(c.getHealth() > 0){
               blablabla
         }
```

or the recommended way is change your method sigature

```
playerCombat(ArrayList<YourCharacterClass > attacking, ArrayList<YourCharacterClass > targets){
```

Note:

Java already have a Character class name which is a wrapper of `char` better to rename your class to some custom name.

Comment: Bad advice to a Java newbie; he needs to parameterize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList object don't have the getHealth method,But character class.

Modify your function definition as this :

public static void playerCombat(ArrayList <Charcter> attacking, ArrayList<Charcter>  targets){